# returning pointer of a local variable to main() function

Tags: c

I am trying to return the value stored in a local variable to the main() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *func();
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = func();
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}

int *func()
{
    int x = 5, *p;
    p = &x;
    return p;
}
```

The first printf() statement gives output = 5, but the second printf() statement gives a garbage value as output.

I know that the local variable 'x' will not exist after the function "func()" terminates. Then why is it printing 5 for the first printf() statement?? 
Please tell me what is happening inside the code.

Comment: Is there a problem with your spacebar - indentation of your code would be nice

Answer (score 3):

When `func` is invoked, it creates a stack for its local variables `x` and `p`. However, when it returns, this stack is destroyed. Therefore, `p` points a value that has already been destroyed, so its behavior is undefined.